# How to prevent a php file from direct opening

Tags: php

I'm using $_GET method like this

```
if($_GET['page']=="first") {include('pages/first.php');}
```

But how do 404 when user reach example.com/pages/first.php ?
Thanks

Comment: You could keep them outside of the web directory - you can include them, but they wouldn't be accessible to browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a .htaccess file to your 'pages' folder with the following contents:

```
Deny from all
```

Please take note that this will prevent access to all files in this directory, so you should put your public files in a different directory.